# OpenTK Y is completely inverted

Tags: c#, opentk

Hello I am using c# and OpenTK.

For some reason i have my y completely inverted when using the mouse i need to set y negative to be right, but when i am rendering a map the map is inverted i have been trying to find the problem but i cant find what makes the y be inverted.

I will be letting a link for the c# project if the problem is not at the code below.

Game.cs where the on render, on load or on update funcions ate

```
    using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace PlatformGame
{
    class Game : GameWindow
    {

        public static int GridSize = 32, TileSize = 1024;

        Texture2D Texture, TileSet;
        Texture2D Water;
        Texture2D Grass;

        View view;

        Level level;

        public Game(int width,int height)
            : base(width,height)
        {
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

            view = new View(Vector2.Zero, 1.0, 0.0);

            Input.Initialize(this);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            Water = ContentPipe.LoadTexture("Water.png");
            Grass = ContentPipe.LoadTexture("Grass.png");
            TileSet = ContentPipe.LoadTexture("Tiles.png");
            level = new Level("Content/Level.tmx");
        }

        protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

            if(Input.MousePress(OpenTK.Input.MouseButton.Left))
            {
                Vector2 pos = new Vector2(Mouse.X, Mouse.Y) - new Vector2(Width, Height) / 2f;
                pos = view.ToWorld(pos);
                view.SetPosition(pos, View.TweenType.QuarticOut, 15);
            }

            if (Input.Keydown(OpenTK.Input.Key.Right))
            {
                view.SetPosition(view.PositionGoTo + new Vector2(5, 0), View.TweenType.QuarticOut, 15);
            }

            if (Input.Keydown(OpenTK.Input.Key.Left))
            {
                view.SetPosition(view.PositionGoTo + new Vector2(-5, 0), View.TweenType.QuarticOut, 15);
            }

            if (Input.Keydown(OpenTK.Input.Key.Up))
            {
                view.SetPosition(view.PositionGoTo + new Vector2(0, 5), View.TweenType.QuarticOut, 15);
            }

            if (Input.Keydown(OpenTK.Input.Key.Down))
            {
                view.SetPosition(view.PositionGoTo + new Vector2(0, -5), View.TweenType.QuarticOut, 15);
            }

            view.Update();
            Input.Update();

        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);          //Clear Window
            GL.ClearColor(Color.CornflowerBlue);               //Set Windo background to Corn flower blue

            SpriteBatch.Begin(Width, Height);
            view.ApplyTransform();

            for (int x = 0; x < level.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < level.Height; y++)
                {
                    RectangleF Source = new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    switch (level[x,y].Type)
                    {
                        case BlockType.Ladder:
                            Source = new RectangleF(0 * TileSize, 2 * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                            break;
                        case BlockType.Water:
                            Source = new RectangleF(0 * TileSize, 0 * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                            break;
                        case BlockType.Stone:
                            Source = new RectangleF(0 * TileSize, 1 * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                            break;
                        case BlockType.Platform:
                            Source = new RectangleF(1 * TileSize, 1 * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                            break;
                        case BlockType.Dirt:
                            Source = new RectangleF(2 * TileSize, 0 * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                            break;
                        case BlockType.Grass:
                            Source = new RectangleF(1 * TileSize, 0 * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                            break;
                        case BlockType.LadderPlatform:
                            Source = new RectangleF(2 * TileSize, 1 * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                            break;
                    }

                    SpriteBatch.Draw(TileSet, new Vector2(x * GridSize, y * GridSize), new Vector2((float)GridSize / TileSize), Color.Transparent, Vector2.Zero, Source);
                }
            } 

            SwapBuffers();
        }
    }
}
```

View.cs what controls the camera

```
    using System;
using System.Drawing;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

namespace PlatformGame
{
    class View
    {

        public enum TweenType
        {
            Instante,
            Linear,
            QuadraticInOut,
            CubicInOut,
            QuarticOut,
        }

        private Vector2 position;
        /// <summary>
        /// In radians, + = clockwise
        /// </summary>
        public double rotation;
        /// <summary>
        /// 1 = no zoom
        /// 2 = 2x zoom
        /// </summary>
        public double zoom;

        private Vector2 PositionGoto, PositionFrom;
        private TweenType tweenType;
        private int CurrentStep, TweenStep;

        public Vector2 Position
        {
            get
            {
                return position;
            }
        }
        public Vector2 PositionGoTo
        {

            get { return PositionGoto; }
        }

        public Vector2 ToWorld(Vector2 input)
        {
            input /= (float)zoom;
            Vector2 dX = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation),(float)Math.Sin(rotation));
            Vector2 dY = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation + MathHelper.PiOver2), (float)Math.Sin(rotation + -MathHelper.PiOver2));

            return (position + dX * input.X + dY * input.Y);
        }

        public View(Vector2 StartPosition,double StartZoom = 1.0, double StartRotation = 0.0)
        {
            position = StartPosition;
            zoom = StartZoom;
            rotation = StartRotation;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            if (CurrentStep < TweenStep)
            {
                CurrentStep++;
                switch (tweenType)
                {
                    case TweenType.Linear:
                        position = PositionFrom + (PositionGoto - PositionFrom) * GetLinear((float)CurrentStep / TweenStep);
                        break;
                    case TweenType.QuadraticInOut:
                        position = PositionFrom + (PositionGoto - PositionFrom) * GetQuadraticInOut((float)CurrentStep / TweenStep);
                        break;
                    case TweenType.CubicInOut:
                        position = PositionFrom + (PositionGoto - PositionFrom) * GetCubicInOut((float)CurrentStep / TweenStep);
                        break;
                    case TweenType.QuarticOut:
                        position = PositionFrom + (PositionGoto - PositionFrom) * GetQuarticOut((float)CurrentStep / TweenStep);
                        break;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                position = PositionGoto;
            }
        }

        public void SetPosition(Vector2 NewPosition)
        {
            position = NewPosition;
            PositionFrom = NewPosition;
            PositionGoto = NewPosition;
            tweenType = TweenType.Instante;
            CurrentStep = 0;
            TweenStep = 0;
        }

        public void SetPosition(Vector2 NewPosition, TweenType type, int NumSteps)
        {
            PositionFrom = position;
            position = NewPosition;
            PositionGoto = NewPosition;
            tweenType = type;
            CurrentStep = 0;
            TweenStep = NumSteps;
        }

        public float GetLinear(float t)
        {
            return t;
        }

        public float GetQuadraticInOut(float t)
        {
            return (t * t) / ((2 * t * t) - (2 * t) + 1);
        }

        public float GetCubicInOut(float t)
        {
            return (t * t * t) / ((3 * t * t) - (3 * t) + 1);
        }

        public float GetQuarticOut(float t)
        {
            return -((t - 1) * (t - 1) * (t - 1) * (t - 1)) + 1;
        }

        public void ApplyTransform()
        {
            Matrix4 transfotm = Matrix4.Identity;

            transfotm = Matrix4.Mult(transfotm, Matrix4.CreateTranslation(-position.X, -position.Y, 0));
            transfotm = Matrix4.Mult(transfotm, Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(-(float)rotation));
            transfotm = Matrix4.Mult(transfotm, Matrix4.CreateScale((float)zoom, (float)zoom, 1.0f));

            GL.MultMatrix(ref transfotm);
        }
    }
}
```

Project [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4nux9gol9em44i/PlatformGame.7z?dl=0)

Comment: What do yo mean by y is inverted? Mouse coordinates start in top left corner with 0/0 and go to screen.width / screen.height (bottom right). The origin of opentk is in the bottom left corner. It is by design that y is inverted.

Comment: @ThomasVoß but the map It's upside down for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem the the problem is in the spritebatch.cs

it have a line like this:

```
GL.Ortho(-ScreenWidth / 2f, ScreenWidth / 2f, -ScreenHeight / 2f, ScreenHeight / 2f, 0f, 1f);
```

it is suppose to be like this

```
GL.Ortho(-ScreenWidth / 2f, ScreenWidth / 2f, ScreenHeight / 2f, -ScreenHeight / 2f, 0f, 1f);
```